# jCarousel - option scroll

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

i'm trying to port my application to last version of jCarousel

seems that option 'scroll' (the number of items to scroll by) is remove from options. is this right? accordingly to docs, it is present in 2.x version but not in 3.x

simple code like this

```
$('#.jcarousel').jcarousel({
    'scroll': 4
});
```

not apply 'scroll' to carousel

someone have got the same problem?
is there some workaround to solve?

here docs:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/

Comment: link to docs perhaps?

Comment: yes now its not in . you can do the trick by event scroll and jquery